# How can I get the innermost template parameter type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

### Q

In a dummy example of a class

```
typedef myStruct<myStruct<myStruct<int>>> mv;
```

`int` is the innermost template parameter. **How can I get the type of that parameter for arbitrary nesting depth?**

### Desired Result

A mechanism to acquire the innermost type

```
innermost<mv>::type -> int
```

### WishList

1. Can this be done using template aliases (template template parameters are a missing feature here)?
2. In an example where my type would be

   ```
   vector<vector<vector<int>>>
   ```

   Is there a way to perform the same operation, given that `vector` expects an extra template parameter ? Ofcourse a distinct implementation could be divised but is there a way to scale the solution for the first problem to handle these cases as well ?

Comment: What is the use case exactly ? (I suspect an XY problem). C++ doesnt support reflection so there is no general/standard solution to this

Comment: @quantev Purely a metaprogramming quiz to solve exactly what it says. It's a kind of **spot the expert** exercise (even though I kind of already know the 3 people that can easily answer this - you can watch such questions in my profile to see the usual suspects)

Comment: What of `vector<map<int, int>>`, should the inner type be `std::pair<int const, int>` ? Or are mixed templates not allowed ? As it is, it feels underspecified.

Comment: @MatthieuM. No, they're not allowed, we'd have branching solutions

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: So, to sum up: it's *only* the first template parameter (not matter how many), and the solution only needs to work if the template class is always the same. Does the solution need to verify that the template class is always the same (seems difficult, but maybe doable).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, even though I must admit I wasn't thinking of varying inner templates; `vector<list<vector<int>>>` doesn't look like an absurd problem, but wasn't asking for neither the verification nor the extension to varying inner templates (since you thought of the extra problem it would be interesting to see an approach)

Comment: @Nikos, Thanks for posting this "metaprogramming quiz", it just helped me with a real world problem.  I'm working on a class wrapper for V8 like the late https://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/wiki/ClassWrap and this solves the problem where I want to use Opt<T> to flag optional parameters for method calls.  Thanks also to 0x499602D2 and  Matthieu M for the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following. It also returns a tuple if the template has more than one element:

```c++
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct innermost_impl
{
    using type = T;
};

template<template<typename> class E, typename T>
struct innermost_impl<E<T>>
{
    using type = typename innermost_impl<T>::type;
};

template<template<typename...> class E, typename... Ts>
struct innermost_impl<E<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<typename innermost_impl<Ts>::type...>;
};

template<typename T>
using innermost = typename innermost_impl<T>::type;

template<class>
struct X;

static_assert(std::is_same<innermost<X<X<X<int>>>>, int>::value, "");

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: Cool. Would be nice if it worked for non-template types as well ... (so it could be generally used inside templates), in which case the non-template type is returned (or not ?)

Comment: @quantdev You'd probably have to make a bunch of specializations for templates that take non-types. Unfortunately there's no template construct as of yet that can represent non-types.

Comment: This does not actually work with `X` being `std::vector` ([see here](http://ideone.com/udjfMi)), you would have to revise the handling of `E<Ts...>` to only use the first element there; but then the behavior on `map` might be surprising.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I know. Have a solution?

Comment: Not until the desired behavior for `std::map` is specified. If we always take the first parameter it's easy, but if what we really want is the inner *element* in this case, I see no generic way :x

Answer (score 8):

Building on [0x499602D2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187583/147192), we get the following to only consider the first template parameter if ever there are several. And yes it [compiles](http://ideone.com/5dOW1l). It's also slightly simpler.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct innermost_impl
{
    using type = T;
};

template<template<typename...> class E, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct innermost_impl<E<Head, Tail...>>
{
    using type = typename innermost_impl<Head>::type;
};

template<typename T>
using innermost = typename innermost_impl<T>::type;

template<class>
struct X;

static_assert(std::is_same<innermost<X<X<X<int>>>>, int>::value, "");

static_assert(
    std::is_same<innermost<std::vector<X<std::vector<int>>>>, int>::value,
    ""
);

int main()
{
}
```

Note that no attempt is made to validate that the same template is used over and over.

Comment: Reminds me of Alexandrescu's typelists and template cascading! +1 Nice technique