# Retrieve innermost template type within the template itself

Tags: c++, templates, types

is it possible to retrieve the innermost type of stacked templates of the same type *from within the template*? I'd like to retrieve the `double` type in the following example:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_a : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<
        is_a<T>::value,
        T::type, // if it's an A, go deeper
        T>;      // if not, we're done
};
template<typename T>
struct is_a<A<T>> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    A<A<A<A<A<double>>>>>::type d = 3.0;
    return 0;
}
```

It was motivated by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187323/how-can-i-get-the-innermost-template-parameter-type). Also, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords), indicating that it may have something do to with `typename` or `template` keyword placing, but I couldn't get it to work myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual trick to do it with your original approach is to defer evaluation:

```
template<class T> struct type_identity { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    using type = typename std::conditional_t<
        is_a<T>::value,
        T,
        type_identity<T>>::type;
};
```

Comment: Gotta accept this one because it's closer to the original question. Now we have both approaches in here, this is a good thing

Answer (score 34):

Unless I'm missing something I'd just partially specialize a template to make things easier

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct A<A<T>>
{
    using type = typename A<T>::type;
};

int main()
{
    A<double>::type a = 5.0;
    A<A<double>>::type d = 3.0;
    A<A<A<double>>>::type c = 9.5;
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BacWbAauPRErgvlp)</kbd>

Comment: Holy crap this is clever. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, it doesn't seem to work if i only stack 2 A: `A<A<double>>::type`?

Comment: Yes this doesn't work for use case A<A<double>>::type d = 3.0;

Comment: What's the third specialization one for? Seems to work without

Comment: @ThomasB. yes, the third one was test code leftover. Removed.

Comment: I think this is a good example of a procedurally minded approach vs a functionally minded approach. Using `conditional_t` (analogous to `if` and `else`) is a procedurally minded approach, while template specialisation is a functionally minded approach (analogous to pattern matching). It might be worth mentioning that inheriting from `A<T>`  might be worthwhile if there's more to the class than just a type alias.

Answer (score 3):

Besides your typo of missing a `typename`, the problem here:

```
using type = std::conditional_t<
    is_a<T>::value,
    T::type, // if it's an A, go deeper
    T>;      // if not, we're done
```

is that `std::conditional` is not short-circuit. When `T` doesn't have `type` member, this will cause an error.

You can write a meta function to recursively extract the inner type:

```
template<class T>
struct extract_type {
    using type = T;
};

template<class T> class A;

template<class T>
struct extract_type<A<T>> {
    using type = typename extract_type<T>::type;
};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    using type = typename extract_type<T>::type;
};

int main()
{
    A<A<A<A<A<double>>>>>::type d = 3.0;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enable_if` and SFINAE to select the innermost type like that:

```
template<typename T, class Enable = void>
struct A {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T, typename T::type>>> {
   using type = typename T::type;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Marco's (correct) answer. You may want to put some of this type-selection logic into a traits class:

```
// step 1 - predeclare the template A

template<typename T> struct A;

// define a default specialisation of a traits type
template<class T> struct ATraits
{
    using type = T;
};

// specialise the traits for the A<T> case
template<class T> struct ATraits<A<T>>
{
    using type = typename A<T>::type;
};

// now define the A template default specialisation
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    using type = typename ATraits<T>::type;
};

int main()
{
    A<A<A<A<A<double>>>>>::type d = 3.0;
    return 0;
}
```