# How to obtain inner type of template type?

Tags: c++, templates

I've got the following situation:

This is a wrapper type

```
template <typename wrapperInnerType>
struct wrapperT{ ... };
using wrapper = wrapperT<float>;
```

And it's used in this class

```
template <typename wrapperType>
class InData{
    wrapperInnerType var;   //<-- How to get inner type?
};
```

My question is what is the easiest way to get wrapperInnerType from wrapperType?

Ideally I would like it to be still possible to use `InData<wrapper> myData;` when using that class (instead of having multiple types in declaration like in `InData<wrapper, float> myData;` as an example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the innermost template parameter type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187323/how-can-i-get-the-innermost-template-parameter-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to define a type alias in `wrapperT`.

```
template <typename wrapperInnerType>
struct wrapperT {
    using innerType = T;
    // ...
};
using wrapper = wrapperT<float>;

template <typename wrapperType>
class InData{
    typename wrapperType::innerType var;
};
```

Another approach could be to make a helper struct that extract it using a template template parameter and partial specialization. This would avoid having to modify `wrapperT` and could potentially give some re-usability. The template signature of `wrap` would however have to be known for this to work.

```
template <typename T>
struct getInnerType;

template <template <typename> typename wrap, typename Inner>
struct getInnerType<wrap<Inner>> {
    using type = Inner;
}

template <typename T> // For more convenient use as pointed out in comments
using getInnerType_t = typename getInnerType<T>::type

template <typename wrapperType>
class InData{
    getInnerType_t<wrapperType> var;   //<-- How to get inner type?
};
```

Comment: And also `template <typename T> using getInnerType_t = typename getInnerType<T>::type;` to simplify usage in `InData`.

Comment: Thanks, went with the first approach and it's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed, why not. Added.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `template <typename> typename wrap` called?(or if you had some reference to better understand how it works)

Comment: That's a template template parameter, cppref has a reasonable explanation. @tangy

Answer (score 3):

You could declare the following class template, `wrapper_inner_type`:

```
template<typename>
struct wrapper_inner_type;
```

Then, specialize it for the wrapper, `wrapperT<InnerType>`, where `InnerType` is the type you want to find out:

```
template<typename InnerType>
struct wrapper_inner_type<wrapperT<InnerType>> {
   using type = InnerType;
};
```

You can also define this alias template for convenience:

```
template<typename T>
using wrapper_inner_type_t = typename wrapper_inner_type<T>::type;
```

Finally, in order to get the inner type inside `InData`:

```
template <typename wrapperType>
class InData{
    wrapper_inner_type_t<wrapperType> var;
};
```